# Custom table creation into SSAS server

Tags: ssas

I want to create an dimension table for time data in my datawarehouse server (hours, minutes and seconds) like this article :

[http://www.rad.pasfu.com](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/122-Script-for-Creating-and-Generating-members-for-Time-Dimension.html)

But my problem is how to create this table in the server like the case of date dimension, on the SSAS Server and not in the data source, because I don't have access to write on it!
There are a solution to do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you will need to use the Dimension Wizard and generate a Time Dimension on Server.

1.Right Click dimensions->Add new Dimension
 2.Generate a Time Table on the Server
 3.Configure your Time Dimension here(Range,Periods etc)
 4.Process it

Also See below link 
.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/create-a-time-dimension-by-generating-a-time-table?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: A time dimension created with wizard contain only dates no time with hours, minutes ...

Comment: My Bad , i've  now noticed that you wanted Hours,seconds etc. If you already have a date dimension perhaps you could create a named query in DSV  with all variations for DateKey  and Time(hours,seconds)( but it might affect performance ) and join it  to your date dimension on datekey otherwise  i believe that might not be possible to achieve only from cube in Multidimensional mode

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSAS Tabular, then starting with SSAS 2016 a DAX expression can be used to create a calculated table.  Calculated tables are not stored in the data source and are evaluated upon processing the Tabular model.  The table can be created in SSDT by either going to the top menu and selecting **Table** > **New Calculated Table** or pressing the green plus sign (**+**) from the grid view and entering the DAX expression.  For this, the start and end dates may be used as the parameters of the `CALENDAR` function.  After the table is initially created calculated columns can be added to the table using the date part function which corresponds to the necessary date element.  For example, use `YEAR` for the year column, `HOUR` for the hour column, `MINUTE` for the minute column, and so on.  The [DAX reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/date-and-time-functions-dax) for date and time functions further details these.

Comment: Thx @userfl89 Unfortunately, I'm using multidimensional project in visual studio 2017, and I can't found new calculate table menu, but named query with which I tried to create a temporary table, the same thing no permission !